# Javascript/HTMl Quiz - how do I add images to act as a potential answer

Tags: javascript, html, web

im currently trying to create a picture quiz that utlises this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/

the issue I am having is changing this quiz from a solely text based affair into a picture quiz. for example the quiz will ask a question such as "which of these pictures is a giraffe?", the user then will have to select an answer that has a giraffe picture.

Below is the current version of the js script i have (admittedly, not much has changed, due to not being able to figure images out)

```js
(function(){
  // Functions
  function buildQuiz(){
    // variable to store the HTML output
    const output = [];

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach(
      (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // variable to store the list of possible answers
        const answers = [];

        // and for each available answer...
        for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){

          // ...add an HTML radio button
          answers.push(
            `<label>
              <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}">
              ${letter} :
              ${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}
            </label>`
          );
        }

        // add this question and its answers to the output
        output.push(
          `<div class="slide">
            <div class="question"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
            <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
          </div>`
        );
      }
    );

    // finally combine our output list into one string of HTML and put it on the page
    quizContainer.innerHTML = output.join('');
  }

  function showResults(){

    // gather answer containers from our quiz
    const answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

    // keep track of user's answers
    let numCorrect = 0;

    // for each question...
    myQuestions.forEach( (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

      // find selected answer
      const answerContainer = answerContainers[questionNumber];
      const selector = `input[name=question${questionNumber}]:checked`;
      const userAnswer = (answerContainer.querySelector(selector) || {}).value;

      // if answer is correct
      if(userAnswer === currentQuestion.correctAnswer){
        // add to the number of correct answers
        numCorrect++;

        // color the answers green
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'lightgreen';
      }
      // if answer is wrong or blank
      else{
        // color the answers red
        answerContainers[questionNumber].style.color = 'red';
      }
    });

    // show number of correct answers out of total
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = `${numCorrect} out of ${myQuestions.length}`;
  }

  function showSlide(n) {
    slides[currentSlide].classList.remove('active-slide');
    slides[n].classList.add('active-slide');
    currentSlide = n;
    if(currentSlide === 0){
      previousButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else{
      previousButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    if(currentSlide === slides.length-1){
      nextButton.style.display = 'none';
      submitButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }
    else{
      nextButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
      submitButton.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  function showNextSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide + 1);
  }

  function showPreviousSlide() {
    showSlide(currentSlide - 1);
  }

  // Variables
  const quizContainer = document.getElementById('quiz');
  const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
  const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
 

  const myQuestions = [
      
    {
      question: "Who invented JavaScript?",
      answers: {
        a: "Douglas Crockford",
        b: "Sheryl Sandberg",
        c: "Brendan Eich"
      },
      correctAnswer: "a"
    },
    {
      question: "is my name davet?",
      answers: {
        a: "Douglas Crockford",
        b: "Sheryl Sandberg",
        c: "yes"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Which one of these is a JavaScript package manager?",
      answers: {
        a: "Node.js",
        b: "TypeScript",
        c: "npm"
      },
      correctAnswer: "c"
    },
    {
      question: "Which tool can you use to ensure code quality?",
      answers: {
        a: "Angular",
        b: "jQuery",
        c: "RequireJS",
        d: "ESLint"
      },
      correctAnswer: "d"
    }
    
    
  ];

  // Kick things off
  buildQuiz();

  // Pagination
  const previousButton = document.getElementById("previous");
  const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");
  const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
  let currentSlide = 0;

  // Show the first slide
  showSlide(currentSlide);

  // Event listeners
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', showResults);
  previousButton.addEventListener("click", showPreviousSlide);
  nextButton.addEventListener("click", showNextSlide);
})();
```

Below is the current HTML I have

```
 <h1>Quiz on Important Facts</h1>
    <div class="quiz-container">
      <div id="quiz"></div>
       <img id="myImg">
    </div>
    <button id="previous">Previous Question</button>
    <button id="next">Next Question</button>
    <button id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <link href="newcss1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.rtl.min.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="newjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, just display several pictures and add an event listener to them and see if it's right...

Comment: Yes user should be asked a question and the answer should be selected from a range of 4 differing pictures.

Comment: If you inspect the code you'll see that each answer is basically a label element with a radio input element inside it. If you style the label elements to have a width and a height when you want the answers to have images and make the image associated with that answer into the background image for that label then everything else should work. i.e. you don't have to add extra eventListeners or anything like that.